# How to Sum column using group by in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
------------------------------------
Item         |     Box
------------------------------------
10           |      25
------------------------------------
12           |      50
------------------------------------
3            |      25
------------------------------------
4            |      30
------------------------------------
6            |      50
------------------------------------
```

Output Should be

```
[25] => 13   , [50] => 18, [30] => 4
```

I am using following query but i am getting the result

```
  select sum(item) as qt  from table group by box
```

Please help me to solve my problem

Comment: What's the problem with your code? You should add the `box` column to the `select` but you should get the sums already.

Comment: _but i am getting the result_ -> what is the problem if you're getting the result

Comment: select sum(item) as qt,box  from table group by box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT sum(item) as qt, box
FROM tablename
GROUP BY box
ORDER BY qt
```